# perl, using File::Find is it possible to modify datastructure outside of that function?

Tags: perl

I am trying to traverse file in each folder and get info from that file and update it to array
For ex.

```
use File::Find;

sub main
{
    my @names = ();
    my $dir = "mydir";        

    # will traverse directories and look for file 'list.txt'
    ### now, is it possible to update @names while traversing using find?
    find(\&getNames(), $dir);

}

sub getNames
{
    #I tried to take names as argument but it doesn't seem to work..
    if (-f $_ && $_ eq 'list.txt')
    {
         #update names possible?
    }
}
```

Is it possible to update data structure while traversing using File::Find?
 And I am trying not to use global variable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it very must is possible, using a nifty feature called closures or anonymous subroutines.

Try changing your find invocation to something like this:

```
find( sub { getNames(\@names, @_) }, $dir);
```

Here, I'm defining a closure that in-turn calls your function 'getNames', with a reference to your data structure as the first parameter followed by any additional arguments supplied by find itself.

In getNames, you can retrieve the data structure as the first parameter:

```
sub getNames
{
    my @names = shift;
    ...
```

Use the array as you like, and nothing else needs to change.

Also, read about closures in Perl: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What%27s-a-closure%3F

Comment: This should be `$names_ref` instead of `@names` in `sub getNames`.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to use an iterator-based file finding module like `File::Next`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Next;

my $iterator = File::Next::files( '.' );

while ( my $file = $iterator->() ) {
    if ( $file eq 'list.txt' ) {
        print "Found list.txt\n";
    }
}
```

Doing it this way, you don't have to worry about the scope of the function that you're in.

You can also let File::Next do the filtering for you:

```
my $iterator = File::Next::files( {
        file_filter => sub { $_ eq 'list.txt' },
    }, '.' );

while ( my $file = $iterator->() ) {
    # No need to check, because File::Next does the filtering
    print "Found list.txt\n";
}
```

Comment: Does it traverse sub-directories as well?

Comment: Yes, of course.  If there's no directory traversal, then all you need is the glob() function.  http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Next/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need `getNames` elsewhere, then you can define this subroutine inside of `main` as an anonymous subroutine. `@names` is available in this subroutine.

```
use File::Find;

sub main
{
    my @names = ();
    my $dir = "mydir";        

    my $getNames = sub
    {
        if (-f $_ && $_ eq 'list.txt')
        {
             #update names possible? -> yes, @names is visible here
        }
    };

    # will traverse directories and look for file 'list.txt'
    ### now, is it possible to update @names while traversing using find?
    find($getNames, $dir);

}
```